# How to make insert validation from some array?

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server

I encountered problems when validating insert data stored in an array
. In this case I have 2 data that I insert simultaneously. Both data before the insert process into the database through the process of checking the stock. Here's my code

[image: a busy cat]

I've tried with PHP 5 and web server is Apache 2 and database is SQL-Server 2008

```
<?php

$PartID     = $_POST['PartID'];
$QtyRequest = $_POST['QtyRequest'];
$UnitID     = $_POST['UnitID'];
$LocationID = $_POST['LocationID'];
$MPROSector = $_POST['MPROSector'];
$Notes      = $_POST['Notes'];
$count      = count($PartID);

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    /*VALIDASI CEK STOK*/
    $text = "SELECT SUM(Qty) as QtyStock FROM buku_stock201905 where PartID='$PartID[$i]' AND LocationID='$LocationID[$i]'";
    $q    = sqlsrv_query($conn, $text);
    while ($r = sqlsrv_fetch_array($q, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $QtyStock = $r['QtyStock'];
    }

    if ($QtyRequest[$i] >= $QtyStock) {
        echo "<script>alert('Gagal Menyimpan MPRO, Stock Tidak Cukup');history.go(-1);</script>";
    } else {
        $queryhd               = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sqlhd);
        $query                 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $updatereq);
        $queryinsertdt         = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sqldt);
        $queryinsertobukustock = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sqlbukustock);
        echo "<script>alert('Berhasil Menyimpan MPRO');history.go(-1);</script>";
    }
}
?>
```

I check the stock means enough, which I cross the stock is not enough. when I click save both enter the database. I want only the stock data is enough. How? . and there are data alerts where the stock is not enough if there is one data that can enter the insert

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using. Using the low-level `sqlrv_query` functions is not recommended.

Comment: It's also really problematic to define a bunch of queries *somewhere* and then run them arbitrarily. You want to have the query visible on the line you're executing it so you know exactly what is about to happen. Here `$sqlhd` could be anything, you have no idea. You also capture return values you ignore when they could be important errors you need to respond to.

Comment: @tadman i have previous code, but the problem is there. `$sqlhd` also in previous code. and my program is only working in local. so, i'm not worry about **SQL INJECTION**

Comment: Look, I'm going to stop you there. **ALWAYS, ALWAYS WORRY ABOUT SQL INJECTION**. Mistakes happen. It's very easy to forget to fix something when you're in a rush to go live. If you do it properly the first time not only does that never happen, but you save tons of time you'd otherwise waste tracking down silly escaping issues. Placeholder statements are easier. They will pay dividends immediately. There is no excuse to not use them, especially not "it's just for testing" which is how most disasters start out.